# Why does my whereHas query error out with undefined method "getHasCompareKey()"?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, eloquent

I have a model `Job` which is attached to one model `Project`.

Here are the class definitions:

```
class Job extends Model
{
    public function project() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Project');
    }
}

class Project extends Model
{
    public function jobs() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Job');
    }
}
```

I'm trying to query the `Jobs` collection and filter on either `jobs.title` or `project.title`.

Here is my current search query:

```
$jobs = Job::where(function($query) use ($searchTerm) {
            $query->where('title', 'LIKE', $searchTerm)
                    ->orWhereHas('project', function ($subQuery) use ($searchTerm) {
                            return $subQuery->where('title', 'LIKE', $searchTerm);
                    });
        })->get();
```

However, this is returning an error:

`Call to undefined method Jenssegers\Mongodb\Query\Builder::getHasCompareKey()`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to clean up your code a bit:

```
$jobs = Job::where('title', 'LIKE', $searchTerm)
            ->orWhereHas('project', function ($query) use ($searchTerm) {
                            $query->where('title', 'LIKE', $searchTerm);
                        })->get();
```

Comment: This gives me the same error. My inner subquery is a bit more complicated than posted, which is why I wrapped it in the first place.